# Lowest surface-to-volume ratio for an uncovered vessel

Tags: geometry

It is well known that a sphere has the lowest surface to volume ratio. However, a related question is: What is the shape that gives the lowest surface to volume ratio if you do not include the *top* in the surface. That is, what is the maximal volume of an uncovered vessel of a fixed surface area?

To be more specific with the definition of *top* or *cover* -- I regard this as a continuous manifold which allow holes. The holes do not contribute to the *surface*, but the *volume* I consider is only the one up to (*up* defined by the direction of gravity) the first hole. The answer thus depends on the direction of the vessel. An upside-down water glass would have an infinite ratio.

For example, a cylinder whose height is equal to its radius and a missing top basis, has a volume $\pi R^2 h = \pi R^3$ and a surface (without cover) of $\pi R^2 + 2\pi R h = 3 \pi R^2$. If we fix the volume to unity, the surface in this case is $3 \sqrt[3]{\pi}$.

In comparison, a half sphere of unity volume has a smaller surface, *i.e.* $\sqrt[3]{18\pi}$ .

However, it's clear this is not the best shape -- a sphere cut just a little higher the equator beats the half sphere.

So, what is the shape that gives the lowest surface to volume ratio if you do not include the *top* in the surface?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm curious-- will punching an infinetisimally small hole on a spherical vessel do the trick?

Comment: "A sphere cut a big above half its volume beats the half sphere." True. Now take that to its logical conclusion: A sphere cut arbitrarily-close to its North Pole gets arbitrarily-close to the optimal ratio. On the other hand, if you say that the hole must be non-infinitesimal in some way --say, a circle of a given radius-- then one can construct an arbitrarily-large sphere with such a hole, ever-improving the surface-to-volume ratio.

Comment: No. If we limit ourselves to spherical caps, the optimal solution is not the full sphere with an infinitesimal hole, but rather a cap cut at height which is 3/2 times the radius.

Comment: sorry, my mistake. Optimizing with constant volume gives the half sphere as the optimal spherical cap. Still, I wonder what's the best shape in general.